# Telnet not valid when opening command prompt with Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, telnet

When I open a command prompt manually and type the following command I get a response from the server I am pinging.

```
telnet <server> <port>
```

When I open the command prompt with Ruby, using the following command, and run the same telnet command above, I get ''telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

Ruby command:

```
system('start cmd.exe)
```

It opens the prompt fine, but the command itself is not working, and I am not sure to why that is.

Comment: You will need to me more specific. What is run by `cmd.exe`? How are you invoking the command or starting ruby? Can you break this issue down into smaller steps? What if you open an `irb` instance and type in your command there?

Comment: when I am running system('start cmd.exe') it is executing the command prompt executable (to open the command prompt).  I then manually enter the telnet command in the command prompt opened with previous command, and I see the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some good next steps are:

- Locate `telnet.exe` using [`WHERE`](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html), then invoke `system` with the path to `telnet.exe`.
- Instead of `system`, I recommend using [`Open3.popen3()`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Open3.html#method-i-popen3) so that you can interact with the actual telnet program via `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, and `STDERR`.
- Lastly, instead of any of the above options I would suggest that you use [`net-telnet`](https://github.com/ruby/net-telnet) as it exposes an easier API to use versus wrapping the Windows Telnet client.

Comment: Thanks for the response David.  I was not able to execute telnet.exe from within Ruby...but I did use the net-telnet gem you mentioned, and it was able to do what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.exe` is not located at the place from which you have run `irb` (or whatever is your ruby shell.

You need to pass the full-path to `cmd.exe`, include escapes for any [illegal path characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1976050/263858), e.g. `C:\some\folder\path\to\cmd.exe`

```
system('start C:\some\folder\path\to\cmd.exe')
```

Comment: Don't use back-slashes with a double-quoted string. You're asking for problems as several of the backslash+letter combinations are interpreted as escaped characters. Instead, do the easy thing and use forward slashes and let Ruby handle them for you. `"\some\folder\path\to\cmd.exe" # => " ome\folderpath\to\rd.exe"`

Comment: I have tried using both the full path with the following command:
system("start C:/\Windows/\System32/\/cmd.exe")
that opens the prompt as expected, but again, the telnet issues still arises

Comment: @aswerlein511 sure, then you'll need to follow David S's solution for debugging that using `Open3` ruby lib